# Set default wallpaper when building ROM

Tags: android, build, wallpaper

I need to set the default wallpaper in Android when building a ROM. I have built a CM7 based ROM as an example and deleted all wallpaper files except `love_cm`, but at first boot, `cmchrome` is still my default wallpaper.

How do I do that?

Comment: fixed.. how to close this thread?

Comment: you can add vote to delete the post..delete button shows at the end of your question and tags..or you can share your answer to the community..

Answer (score 2):

1) Load framework file in apktool

```
apktool if framework-res.apk
```

2) Decompile it

```
apktool d framework-res.apk
```

3) Navigate to /res/drawable-hdpi/ and delete default_wallpaper.jpg file

4) Copy the jpg file you want to be default wallpaper in /res/drawable-hdpi/ and rename it in default_wallpaper.jpg

5) Navigate to /res/values/ and open strings.xml

6) Change this line
    com.android.wallpaper/.nexus.NexusWallpaper

with this:

```
<string name="default_wallpaper_component">@null</string>
```

7) Compile framework-res.apk

```
apktool b framework-res framework-res-modded.apk
```

8) Sign it (e.g. ApkManager)

9) Rename it in framework-res.apk and push it to ROM flashable zip

Answer (score 0):

open framework-res.apk in system\framework with winrar and search for res/drawablenodpi and other files wich contain defaultwallpaper.jpeg ..